# Specific VBA / VBScript regex related issue (MS Access)

Tags: regex, vba, debugging, vbscript

---

### UPDATE: March 12, 2018 1:44pm CST

After creating a website called http://vbfiddle.net to implement and test @ctwheel's VBScript solution in a browser (MS IE 10+ with Security set to "Medium", instructions on that website for how to set it up for you to play with should you want -- get the code to copy & paste into vbfiddle.net from this link at jsfiddle.net: https://jsfiddle.net/hcwjhmg9/ [**vbfiddle.net does not currently have a "save" feature**] ), I found that @ctwheel's VBScript RegEx ran successfully, even for the 3rd example line I gave, but when @ctwheel's VBScript RegEx is used in VBScript for VBA for Microsoft Access 2016 against a record read from a database with the "same" value, the third subgroup only returns "Ray," for the 3rd example line I gave, when it should return "Ray, CFP" like it does in vbfiddle.net.

It finally occurred to me to iterate through every character of the string value returned by the database (in VBA in Microsoft Access), and compare it to an iteration of every character of the visually-equivalent string value I type directly into the code (in VBA in Microsoft Access). I get the following results:

```
First Name and Last Name: "G.L. (Pete) Ray, CFP"
--- 1st Text chars: "71 46 76 46 32 40 80 101 116 101 41 32 82 97 121 44" 
(Read value from database, appears same as below when Debug.Print is called on it)
--- 2nd Text chars: "71 46 76 46 32 40 80 101 116 101 41 32 82 97 121 44 32 67 70 80" (Typed by keyboard into a string within the code)
'G.L. (Pete) Ray,'
    strProperName>objSubMatch: "G.L."
    strProperName>objSubMatch: "Pete"
    strProperName>objSubMatch: "Ray,"
 Matching record(s): 3 of 1132 record(s).
```

The RegEx I'm running is running against the "`1st Text Chars`" example, and returns "Ray," for the 3rd subgroup of the previously given 3rd example line: "`G.L. (Pete) Ray, CFP`". However, if I run the RegEx against the 2nd -- typed directly into code -- "`2nd Text chars`" example, the 3rd subgroup returns "Ray, CFP" as expected in VBA for Microsoft Access 2016.

I'm now using the RegEx that @ctwheels provided:

```
^([^(]+?)\s*\(\s*([^)]*?)\s*\)\s*(.*)
```

Can someone explain what's going on here? 1) Why are the characters returned from the database different from the characters returned from typing the string using a keyboard by reading and copying it visually? 2) How do I make a RegEx that works on the "`1st Text Chars`" sequence of characters / string return the correct 3rd subgroup: "`Ray, CFP`" when the value is read directly from the database?

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION** (updated question above):

I'm having problems in VBA using Microsoft Access 2016 with Regex Engine I believe 5.5 for VBScript.

This is the regex expression I'm currently using:

```
"(.*)\((.*)(\))(.*)"
```

I'm trying to parse the strings (respectively on each new line):

```
Lawrence N. (Larry) Solomon
James ( Jim ) Alleman
G.L. (Pete) Ray, CFP
```

Into:

```
"Lawrence N.", "Larry", ")", "Solomon"
"James", "Jim", ")", "Alleman"
"G.L.", "Pete", ")", "Ray, CFP"
```

Or alternatively (and preferably) into:

```
"Lawrence N.", "Larry", "Solomon"
"James", "Jim", "Alleman"
"G.L.", "Pete", "Ray, CFP"
```

where the parts within the quotes, separated by commas, are those returned in the submatches (without quotes)

I am using the following code:

```
           ' For Proper Name (strProperName):
            With objRegex
                .Global = False
                .MultiLine = False
                .IgnoreCase = True
                .Pattern = "(.*)\((.*)(\))(.*)"

                    '([\s|\S]*) work around to match every character?

                        '".*\(([^\s]*)[\s]*\(" '_
                        ''& "[\"
                        '[\(][\s]*([.|^\w]*)[\s]*\)"
                    ' "[\s]*(.*)[\s]*\("
                        ' does same as below except matches any or no whitespace preceding any characters,
                        ' and returns the following characters up to an opening parenthesis ("(") but excluding it,
                        ' as the first subgroup
                    ' "(.*)[\s]*\("
                        ' does same as below except matches any whitespace or no whitespace at all followed by an opening parenthesis ("(")
                        ' and returns the preceding characters as the first subgroup
                    ' "(.*)\("
                        ' matches all characters in a row that end with an open parenthesis, and returns all of these characters in a row
                        ' excluding the following open parenthesis as the first subgroup
                    ' "(.*?\(\s)"
                    ' "[^\(]*"
                        ' this pattern returns every character that isn't an opening parenthesis ("("), and when
                        ' it matches an open parenthesis, it does not return it or any characters after it
                    ' "[\(\s](.*)\)"
                        ' this pattern extracts everything between parenthesis in a line as its first submatch
                    ' "(?<=\().*"
                    ' "[^[^\(]*][.*]"
                    ' "(\(.*?\))"
                    ' "(\(.*?\))*([^\(].*[^\)])"
            End With

            If objRegex.Test(strFirstNameTrimmed) Then
                'Set strsMatches = objRegex.Execute(rs.Fields("First Name"))
                Set strsMatches = objRegex.Execute(strFirstNameTrimmed)



                Debug.Print "2:'" & strsMatches(0).Value & "'"

                If strsMatches(0).SubMatches.Count > 0 Then

                    For Each objSubMatch In strsMatches(0).SubMatches

                        Debug.Print "    strProperName>objSubMatch: """ & objSubMatch & """" 'Result: 000, 643, 888"

                        strProperName = objSubMatch

                    Next objSubMatch

                End If
            Else
                strProperName = "*Not Matched*"
            End If
```

Produces the following output in the debug window / "Immediate Window" as it's known in VBA, brought up by (Ctrl+G):

```
------------------------
First Name and Last Name: "Lawrence N. (Larry) Solomon"
2:'Lawrence N. (Larry)'
    strProperName>objSubMatch: "Lawrence N. "
    strProperName>objSubMatch: "Larry"
    strProperName>objSubMatch: ")"
    strProperName>objSubMatch: ""
Extracted Nick Name: "Larry"
Extracted Proper Name: ""
First Name and Last Name: "James ( Jim ) Alleman"
2:'James ( Jim )'
    strProperName>objSubMatch: "James "
    strProperName>objSubMatch: " Jim "
    strProperName>objSubMatch: ")"
    strProperName>objSubMatch: ""
Extracted Nick Name: "Jim"
Extracted Proper Name: ""
First Name and Last Name: "G.L. (Pete) Ray, CFP"
2:'G.L. (Pete) Ray,'
    strProperName>objSubMatch: "G.L. "
    strProperName>objSubMatch: "Pete"
    strProperName>objSubMatch: ")"
    strProperName>objSubMatch: " Ray,"
Extracted Nick Name: "Pete"
Extracted Proper Name: " Ray,"
Matching record(s): 3 of 1132 record(s).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/ER2G8u/1/)

```
^([^(]+?)\s*\(\s*([^)]*?)\s*\)\s*(.*)
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `([^(]+?)` Capture any character except `(` one or more times, but as few as possible, into capture group 1
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
- `\(` Match `(` literally
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
- `([^)]*?)` Capture any character except `)` one or more times, but as few as possible, into capture group 2
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
- `\(` Match `(` literally
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
- `(.*)` Capture the rest of the line into capture group 3

Results in:

```
["Lawrence N.", "Larry", "Solomon"]
["James", "Jim", "Alleman"]
["G.L.", "Pete", "Ray, CFP"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I am reviewing this now.

Comment: In VBA via Microsoft Access 2016, using "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" as a referenced library (via menu: [Tools] > [References...]) and selecting "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" exclusively, and not 1.0. See next comment...

Comment: "Ray," is captured as subgroup 3 for input 3, not "Ray, CFP"... which is actually the main reason I was asking this question, as I want to capture "Ray, CFP" fully in VBA with engine 5.5 via MS Access 2016.

Comment: Also, thank you for the great resource "Regular Expressions 101" online Regex evaluator. To get the idea out there, wouldn't it be cool if this tool or one like it automatically produced a line-item breakdown of the given RegEx like the breakdown you've given? Also, it would be great if this tool or one like it showed the results for various languages using various engines under various conditions, and perhaps ran them all at once.

Comment: Primary response/question: "Ray," is captured as subgroup 3 for input 3, not "Ray, CFP"... which is actually the main reason I was asking this question, as I want to capture "Ray, CFP" fully in VBA with engine 5.5 via MS Access 2016. How do I capture "Ray, CFP" as the 3rd subgroup for the 3rd input?

Comment: @blueuser can you post your (working) code up on [tio.run](https://tio.run/#vb-core) so that this may be tested? Also, regex101 does include that in the top-right corner under *Explanation*

Comment: Primary response/question: "Ray," is captured as subgroup 3 for input 3, not "Ray, CFP"... which is actually the main reason I was asking this question, as I want to capture "Ray, CFP" fully in VBA with engine 5.5 via MS Access 2016. How do I capture "Ray, CFP" as the 3rd subgroup for the 3rd input?

Comment: oh cool, that's amazing thanks. I will get some modified code put together that doesn't require the database input and put it up on tio.run within 30 minutes (by 3:45 CST).

Comment: Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) and/or VBScript is not supported by tio.run . I'll look for an alternative. Can you suggest one?

Comment: ctwheels @ctwheels i'll try putting the code into http://rextester.com/l/vb . Please give me until 3:50PM CST.

Comment: @blueuser the internet is amazing isn't it haha

Comment: There is no working VBScript online editor/compiler, like JSFiddle for Javascript or tio.run. Making one, it will only run in Internet Explorer though as I don't wish to build a server backend. Should take under 3 hours.

Comment: @blueuser no worries then, just thought about it now, but are there any newline characters in your `Ray, CFP` string? Maybe try replacing `(.*)` with `([\s\S]*)`

Comment: ctwheels @ctwheels Ok, I haven't had a chance to get back to this until now. My online VBScript interpreter is now active at http://VBFiddle.net . Please try it out using the latest Microsoft Internet Explorer (yes MS IE is required to use it since it's VBScript) and see if it works on your P.C. If it does (or doesn't) you were my first beta tester. I've also worked on the VBScript that uses the built-in RegEx engine of MS IE VBscript, which I imagine has the same quarks as the VBA VBScript engine in Microsoft Access that I'm using. When I'm done with that I'll let you know...

Comment: ctwheels To see your suggested RegEx code in action as interpretted by VBScript in MS Internet Explorer, go to https://jsfiddle.net/hcwjhmg9/ and select all of the HTML/Vbscript in the HTML pane (Ctrl+A), then copy it (Ctrl+C), then go to http://vbfiddle.net in the latest Microsoft Internet Explorer, and clear the code panel on the left ([Ctrl+A] then [Backspace]), then paste in the HTML/VBScript copied from the provided jsfiddle.net link (Ctrl+V), then press the [Run] button or F8 on your keyboard. The output on the left will show the output of your code.

Comment: ctwheels The output of your code when run under VBScript using MS IE 10+ is CORRECT for the use cases given in that environment, and you answered my question by providing a RegEx valid in working VBScript, so I am awarding you the Accepted Answer, even though I will be using Ryan Wildrey's solution for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to avoid using Regex, if that's your thing.

I made some assumptions about the test data that the nickname is contained within "()". Other than that the code should be straightforward, I hope. If not, feel free to ask a question. There is a Test routine called `Test` included too.

```
Public Function ParseString(InputString As String) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:

    Dim OutputArray   As Variant
    Const DoubleQuote As String = """"

    'Quick exit, if () aren't found, then just return original text
    If InStr(1, InputString, "(") = 0 Or InStr(1, InputString, ")") = 0 Then
        ParseString = InputString
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Replace the ) with (, then do a split
    OutputArray = Split(Replace(InputString, ")", "("), "(")

    'Check the array bounds and output accordingly
    'If there can only ever be 3 (0 - 2) elements, then you can change this if statement
    If UBound(OutputArray) = 2 Then
        ParseString = DoubleQuote & Trim$(OutputArray(0)) & DoubleQuote & ", " & _
                      DoubleQuote & Trim$(OutputArray(1)) & DoubleQuote & ", " & _
                      DoubleQuote & Trim$(OutputArray(2)) & DoubleQuote
    ElseIf UBound(OutputArray) = 1 Then
        ParseString = DoubleQuote & Trim$(OutputArray(0)) & DoubleQuote & ", " & _
                      DoubleQuote & Trim$(OutputArray(1)) & DoubleQuote
    Else
        ParseString = DoubleQuote & Trim$(OutputArray(LBound(OutputArray))) & DoubleQuote
    End If

CleanExit:
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    ParseString = InputString
    Resume CleanExit
End Function

Sub Test()
    Dim Arr() As Variant: Arr = Array("Lawrence N. (Larry) Solomon", "James ( Jim ) Alleman", "G.L. (Pete) Ray, CFP")

    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Debug.Print ParseString(CStr(Arr(i)))
    Next
End Sub
```

**Results**

```
"Lawrence N.", "Larry", "Solomon"
"James", "Jim", "Alleman"
"G.L.", "Pete", "Ray, CFP"
```

Comment: Yes, I had considered the approach of using split, but I thought it a bit complicated to split the string twice on ")" and "(" separately, then recombine the resulting strings. I like your approach, using replace -- very elegant. If I could accept two answers, I would accept yours and the one via RegEx. If the respondent with the RegEx answer satisfies my concerns with specifically the VBScript RegEx (for which his RegEx doesn't handle the hardest and main case I was looking to solve for VBScript RegEx), then I will award you the Accepted Answer. If he does solve it within the next...

Comment: ... 3 days (and I've created an online VBScript webpage similar to jsfiddle.net which I will be calling vbfiddle.net, which should allow him to get his RegEx working in VBScript 5.5) then I will award him the Accepted Answer, and upvote you. Thank you graciously for your time and effort.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to learn RegEx and its quirks in different flavors since RegExes are a weak point for me in software development, and there are many (more complicated) use cases in which understanding RegEx very well will be valuable.

Comment: @blueuser yup, I hear ya with Regex's. They are a powerful tool for sure, but can be overused. Sometimes it's hard to know when to use a regex, vs just handrolling something. If a small function can be written like this, I'd lean on the side of avoiding Regex.

Comment: Ryan, @ctwheels answer worked when I created vbfiddle.net and tested his solution, for the use cases I provided. See the last comments on his proposed solution if you'd like to try out his solution yourself in MS IE 10+ running VBScript. However, there appears to be a big in either VBA or the RegEx engine 5.5 used by Microsoft Access 2016 which causes his RegEx to only return "Ray," for the 3rd subgroup for the 3rd line of test data, when run in that environment, even though it should return "Ray, CFP" for the 3rd subgroup, and does so when using vbfiddle.net.

Comment: So I've determined that there is a bug in either VBA or the RegEx 5.5 engine used by VBScript in Microsoft Access 2016. Given that this bug is not @ctwheels fault, and ctwheels answered the question with a RegEx as I requested, ...

Comment: ... I believe he wins the "Accepted Answer" on an ever slight technicality. I will be using a modified version of your code however in my production version, and I appreciate your help. I have upvoted your answer. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: [`\s*[()]\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/6mCCyY/1)

Details:

- `\s*` matches any whitespace character zero and unlimited times
- `[()]` Match a single character present in the list `(` or `)`

**VBA code**:

```
Dim str As String
str = "Lawrence N. (Larry) Solomon"

Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.Global = True
re.Pattern = "\s*[()]\s*"
re.MultiLine = True

Dim arr As Variant
arr = Strings.Split(re.Replace(str, vbNullChar), vbNullChar)

For Each Match In arr
    Debug.Print (Match)
Next
```

Output:

```
Lawrence N.
Larry
Solomon
```

Comment: Fails on the 3rd line/example.

Comment: ... in Microsoft Access 2016 VBA VbScript, RegEx engine I believe 5.5.