# Specific VBA / VBScript regex related issue

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access, debugging, vbscript

### UPDATE: March 12, 2018 1:44pm CST

Original question located here: [Specific VBA / VBScript regex related issue (MS Access)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49160720/specific-vba-vbscript-regex-related-issue-ms-access)

Here is my follow-up to that question. The original question is also copy-pasted into this follow up question (if you'd like to reference it) after this update part:

After creating a website called http://vbfiddle.net to implement and test @ctwheel's VBScript solution on the original question in an online browser client-side (MS IE 10+ with Security set to "Medium", instructions on that website for how to set it up for you to play with should you want -- get the code to copy & paste into vbfiddle.net from this link at jsfiddle.net: https://jsfiddle.net/hcwjhmg9/ [**vbfiddle.net does not currently have a "save" feature**] ), I found that @ctwheel's VBScript RegEx ran successfully, even for the 3rd example line I gave, but when @ctwheel's VBScript RegEx is used in VBScript for VBA for Microsoft Access 2016 against a record read from a database with the "same" value, the third subgroup only returns "Ray," for the 3rd example line I gave, when it should return "Ray, CFP" like it does in vbfiddle.net.

It finally occurred to me to iterate through every character of the string value returned by the database (in VBA in Microsoft Access), and compare it to an iteration of every character of the visually-equivalent string value I type directly into the code (in VBA in Microsoft Access). I get the following results:

```
First Name and Last Name: "G.L. (Pete) Ray, CFP"
--- 1st Text chars: "71 46 76 46 32 40 80 101 116 101 41 32 82 97 121 44"
(Read value from database, appears same as below when Debug.Print is called on it)
--- 2nd Text chars: "71 46 76 46 32 40 80 101 116 101 41 32 82 97 121 44 32 67 70 80" (Typed by keyboard into a string within the code)
'G.L. (Pete) Ray,'
    strProperName>objSubMatch: "G.L."
    strProperName>objSubMatch: "Pete"
    strProperName>objSubMatch: "Ray,"
 Matching record(s): 3 of 1132 record(s).
```

The RegEx I'm running is running against the "`1st Text Chars`" example, and returns "Ray," for the 3rd subgroup of the previously given 3rd example line: "`G.L. (Pete) Ray, CFP`". However, if I run the RegEx against the 2nd -- typed directly into code -- "`2nd Text chars`" example, the 3rd subgroup returns "Ray, CFP" as expected in VBA for Microsoft Access 2016.

I'm now using the RegEx that @ctwheels provided:

```regex
^([^(]+?)\s*\(\s*([^)]*?)\s*\)\s*(.*)
```

Can someone explain what's going on here? 1) Why are the characters returned from the database different from the characters returned from typing the string using a keyboard by reading and copying it visually? 2) How do I make a RegEx that works on the "`1st Text Chars`" sequence of characters / string return the correct 3rd subgroup: "`Ray, CFP`" when the value is read directly from the database?

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION** (updated question above):

I'm having problems in VBA using Microsoft Access 2016 with Regex Engine I believe 5.5 for VBScript.

This is the regex expression I'm currently using:

```
"(.*)\((.*)(\))(.*)"
```

I'm trying to parse the strings (respectively on each new line):

```
Lawrence N. (Larry) Solomon
James ( Jim ) Alleman
G.L. (Pete) Ray, CFP
```

into:

```
"Lawrence N.", "Larry", ")", "Solomon"
"James", "Jim", ")", "Alleman"
"G.L.", "Pete", ")", "Ray, CFP"
```

Or alternatively (and preferably) into:

```
"Lawrence N.", "Larry", "Solomon"
"James", "Jim", "Alleman"
"G.L.", "Pete", "Ray, CFP"
```

where the parts within the quotes, separated by commas, are those returned in the submatches (without quotes).

I am using the following code:

```
' For Proper Name (strProperName):
With objRegex
    .Global = False
    .MultiLine = False
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "(.*)\((.*)(\))(.*)"

        '([\s|\S]*) work around to match every character?

            '".*\(([^\s]*)[\s]*\(" '_
            ''& "[\"
            '[\(][\s]*([.|^\w]*)[\s]*\)"
        ' "[\s]*(.*)[\s]*\("
            ' does same as below except matches any or no whitespace preceding any characters,
            ' and returns the following characters up to an opening parenthesis ("(") but excluding it,
            ' as the first subgroup
        ' "(.*)[\s]*\("
            ' does same as below except matches any whitespace or no whitespace at all followed by an opening parenthesis ("(")
            ' and returns the preceding characters as the first subgroup
        ' "(.*)\("
            ' matches all characters in a row that end with an open parenthesis, and returns all of these characters in a row
            ' excluding the following open parenthesis as the first subgroup
        ' "(.*?\(\s)"
        ' "[^\(]*"
            ' this pattern returns every character that isn't an opening parenthesis ("("), and when
            ' it matches an open parenthesis, it does not return it or any characters after it
        ' "[\(\s](.*)\)"
            ' this pattern extracts everything between parenthesis in a line as its first submatch
        ' "(?<=\().*"
        ' "[^[^\(]*][.*]"
        ' "(\(.*?\))"
        ' "(\(.*?\))*([^\(].*[^\)])"
End With

If objRegex.Test(strFirstNameTrimmed) Then
    'Set strsMatches = objRegex.Execute(rs.Fields("First Name"))
    Set strsMatches = objRegex.Execute(strFirstNameTrimmed)

    Debug.Print "2:'" & strsMatches(0).Value & "'"

    If strsMatches(0).SubMatches.Count > 0 Then
        For Each objSubMatch In strsMatches(0).SubMatches
            Debug.Print "    strProperName>objSubMatch: """ & objSubMatch & """" 'Result: 000, 643, 888"
            strProperName = objSubMatch
        Next objSubMatch
    End If
Else
    strProperName = "*Not Matched*"
End If
```

Produces the following output in the debug window / "Immediate Window" as it's known in VBA, brought up by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>:

```
------------------------
First Name and Last Name: "Lawrence N. (Larry) Solomon"
2:'Lawrence N. (Larry)'
    strProperName>objSubMatch: "Lawrence N. "
    strProperName>objSubMatch: "Larry"
    strProperName>objSubMatch: ")"
    strProperName>objSubMatch: ""
Extracted Nick Name: "Larry"
Extracted Proper Name: ""
First Name and Last Name: "James ( Jim ) Alleman"
2:'James ( Jim )'
    strProperName>objSubMatch: "James "
    strProperName>objSubMatch: " Jim "
    strProperName>objSubMatch: ")"
    strProperName>objSubMatch: ""
Extracted Nick Name: "Jim"
Extracted Proper Name: ""
First Name and Last Name: "G.L. (Pete) Ray, CFP"
2:'G.L. (Pete) Ray,'
    strProperName>objSubMatch: "G.L. "
    strProperName>objSubMatch: "Pete"
    strProperName>objSubMatch: ")"
    strProperName>objSubMatch: " Ray,"
Extracted Nick Name: "Pete"
Extracted Proper Name: " Ray,"
Matching record(s): 3 of 1132 record(s).
```

Comment: Normally the dot metachar `.` will only match non-linebreak characters. If it's only matching the `Ray` and not `Ray, cps` then there is some kind of linebreak character there (might be invisible). Try this `^([^(]+?)\s*\(\s*([^)]*?)\s*\)\s*([\S\s]*)` instead, where the `[\S\s]` will match any character. If it still only matches `Ray`, then I'm afraid that's the end of the field info... better check that.

Comment: Are you sure that the value being returned from the DB is `G.L. (Pete) Ray, CFP` and not `G.L. (Pete) Ray,`? After reading the value in the code, can you try printing it, just to confirm? Also, although, this may not solve your current problem, but an alternative regex may be [`([^(\n]*)\s*\(([^\n)]*)\)\s*(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/EtUXe6/2)

Comment: @sln sln I already tried that solution in the past, it still returned only Ray,

Comment: @Gurman Gurman Yes I printed both values, the one from the database and the one typed directly into the code, to the console using Debug.Print, and what they print is exactly the same.

Comment: @Gurman ... even when the Debug.Print is surrounded by quotes